# PHP Explode Function

Tags: php, explode

I am working on a PayPal Subscription IPN. The custom variable I send to PayPal looks like this:

5|3

When PayPal send this back to me, it is urlencoded and looks like this:

5%7C3

If I want to use the explode function, can I do the following?

```
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
if(isset($custom))
{
list($id_1, $id_2) = explode('|', $custom);
}
```

or like this?

```
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
if(isset($custom))
{
list($id_1, $id_2) = explode('%7C', $custom);
}
```

How can I do this properly? Thank you!

Comment: If everything is being sent back encoded, run `urldecode()` on them before exploding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use this method

```
$output = explode('|', urldecode($_POST['custom']));
```

Comment: you mean I don't have to urldecode it? PHP does it automatically? oops, never mind I did not read it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
echo urldecode('5%7C3');
```

and after this use `explode` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through urldecode() first, then explode it by the absolute value delimiter

```
$custom = urldecode($_POST['custom']);
if($custom!="")
{
list($id_1, $id_2) = explode('|', $custom);
}
```